# How can I change from hardcoded data into a DB data?

Tags: android

Im making a "Ive Never" game as a school project. Basicly each time you click on a button a new text should appear and the old one dissapear. The problem is that I dont know how connect it to the DBHelperList. On the NeverTheGame.java you can make a list in which lines you want to have on your game. The plan is to take data from the list and put it on the NeverTheGame.java Anny suggestions on how to do that ? (sorry for my bad english )

*NeverTheGame.java*

```
public class NeverTheGame extends AppCompatActivity {


int oldValue;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_never_the_game);
    changeTextOnce();
     changeTextViewValue();

}
private void changeTextViewValue() {
    final String[] neverTasks = {
            "Jag har aldrig kollat på anime.",
            "Jag har aldrig stalkat någon på facebook.",
            "Jag har aldrig svimmat.",
            "Jag har aldrig kollat på Disney Channel.",
            "Jag har aldrig varit med på en fest och tänkt för mig själv'Jag är omringad av idioter'.",
            "Jag har aldrig bett om en lönehörhöjning.",
            "Jag har aldrig argumenterat med någon anonym person på internet.",
            "Jag har aldrig försökt ljuga för någon och det gick åt helvete.",
            "Jag har aldrig trott på gud eller nåt liknade."};
    final TextView changeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neverText);
    Button changeTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.neverButton);
    changeText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NeverTheGame.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

    changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * neverTasks.length);
            if(random == oldValue){
                random = (int) (Math.random() * neverTasks.length);
            }
            changeText.setText(neverTasks[random]);
            oldValue = random;
        }
    });
};
private void changeTextOnce(){
    final TextView changeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neverText);
    Button changeTextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.neverButton);
    changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeText.setText("Go hard!");
        }
    });
}
}
```

*IveNever.java*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IveNever extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lstTask;
private Button playTheGame;
private Button howTo;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
DbHelperList dbHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ive_never);
    dbHelper = new DbHelperList(this);
    lstTask = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstTask);
    loadTaskList();
    howTo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iveNeverHowBtn);
    howTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent go1 = new Intent(IveNever.this, NeverWeb.class);
            startActivity(go1);
        }
    });

    playTheGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playGameBtn);
    playTheGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent go2 = new Intent(IveNever.this, NeverTheGame.class);
            startActivity(go2);
        }
    });
}

public void loadTaskList() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
    if(mAdapter==null){
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.createlinerow,R.id.task_title,taskList);
        lstTask.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    else{
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add,menu);
    //Change menu icon color
    Drawable icon = menu.getItem(0).getIcon();
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add A New Line ")
                    .setMessage("I´ve never.....")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            dbHelper.insertNewTask(task);
                            loadTaskList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .create();

            dialog.show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void deleteTask(View view){
    View parent = (View)view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    Log.e("String", (String) taskTextView.getText());
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    dbHelper.deleteTask(task);
    loadTaskList();
}
}
```

*DBHelperList.java*

```
public class DbHelperList extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME="EDMTDev";
private static final int DB_VER = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE="Task";
public static final String DB_COLUMN = "TaskName";

public DbHelperList(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT NOT NULL);",DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN);
    db.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = String.format("DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS %s",DB_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void insertNewTask(String task){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteTask(String task){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN + " = ?",new String[]{task});
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> getTaskList(){
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]{DB_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return taskList;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. I built the code. I'm not clear where you're stuck. The sample already contains working code that inserts and retrieves data from the DB. Converting "final String[] neverTasks" to the DB is similar to what is already being done in insertNewTask & getTaskList.

Comment: @Elletlar. Thanks for the response. The part whem Im stuck is how exactly I need to write to  convert "final String[] never Task to the D. I would really appriciate if you could show me.

Comment: In onUpgrade, after the DB is created iterate through neverTasks with a for loop and do inserts like you do in insertNewTask. You just need to do 1 insert for each item in the neverTasks array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately it dosent make sense. Is there any way you can show me ilustate me that solution ?

Comment: I added code to insert the 'neverTasks' into the existing DB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting the data into the DB:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT NOT NULL);", DB_TABLE, DB_COLUMN);
    db.execSQL(query);
    insertAll(db);
}

private void insertAll(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   for (String neverTask : neverTasks) {
       values.put(DB_COLUMN, neverTask);
       long rowId = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
       if (rowId != -1) {
           Log.i("insertAll", "Inserted: " + neverTask);
       } else {
           Log.w("insertAll", "failure: " + neverTask);
       }
       // values.clear();
    }
}
```

- Insert returns the row ID if it succeeds (1, 2, 3, ...)
- The app must be uninstalled and reinstalled for the data to be inserted
- To insert data into an existing DB change the DB_VER to 2 and call insertAll from onUpgrade()
- To insert the data into a separate table add to onCreate:

  ```
  final String createTable2 = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT NOT NULL);", DB_TABLE2, DB_TABLE2_COLUMN);
  db.execSQL(createTable2);
  ```

Comment: I did that but for some reason it crashes. Can you look at my code ?

Comment: What line does it crash on? Can you paste the crash log from the 'logcat' tab?

Comment: It comes when im clicking on the Next button in the NeverThe Game.java Error is "05-07 13:45:22.738 11393-11393/com.example.nick.letsgetdrunk12 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nick.letsgetdrunk12, PID: 11393"

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't have anything to do with inserting the data into the DB.

Comment: In logcat, find the callstack for the crash. You should see the last method/function in the stack that was part of your code. If you click on the file name on the right, it will open the editor to the line where it crashed.

Comment: I managed to figure out the crahs and it was beacuse beacuse of the "  final String[] neverTasks" that is empty. So I need to write a get method to the database then ?

Comment: Yes call getTaskList() or write a similar method to get the data from neverTask table. You might have to do something like: "final String[] neverTasks = List.toArray(dbHelper.getTaskList());" if the existing code is to work without modifications.

Comment: I´ve managed to solve the problem by swriting "  ArrayList<String> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
        final String[] neverTasks = taskList.toArray(new String[taskList.size()]);" in changeTextViewValue. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help...Hope the app turns out well :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the app craches. Here is my code.

*DbHelperList.java*

```
public class DbHelperList extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME="EDMTDev";
private static final int DB_VER = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE="Task";
public static final String DB_COLUMN = "TaskName";
String[] neverTasks;

public DbHelperList(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT NOT NULL);",DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN);
    db.execSQL(query);
    insertAll(db);
}

private void insertAll(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    for (String neverTask : neverTasks) {
        values.put(DB_COLUMN, neverTask);
        long rowId = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
        if (rowId != -1) {
            Log.i("insertAll", "Inserted: " + neverTask);
        } else {
            Log.w("insertAll", "failure: " + neverTask);
        }
        // values.clear();
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = String.format("DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS %s",DB_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
    insertAll(db);

}
```

*NeverTheGame.java*

```
  int oldValue;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_never_the_game);
    changeTextOnce();
     changeTextViewValue();

}
private void changeTextViewValue() {
    final String[] neverTasks = {
          /*  "Jag har aldrig kollat på anime.",
            "Jag har aldrig stalkat någon på facebook.",
            "Jag har aldrig svimmat.",
            "Jag har aldrig kollat på Disney Channel.",
            "Jag har aldrig varit med på en fest och tänkt för mig själv'Jag är omringad av idioter'.",
            "Jag har aldrig bett om en lönehörhöjning.",
            "Jag har aldrig argumenterat med någon anonym person på internet.",
            "Jag har aldrig försökt ljuga för någon och det gick åt helvete.",
            "Jag har aldrig trott på gud eller nåt liknade."*/};
    final TextView changeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neverText);
    Button changeTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.neverButton);
    changeText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NeverTheGame.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

    changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * neverTasks.length);
            if(random == oldValue){
                random = (int) (Math.random() * neverTasks.length);
            }
            changeText.setText(neverTasks[random]);
            oldValue = random;
        }
    });
};
```

Correct me if I did something wrong.

Comment: "final String[] neverTasks = {}". It is likely crashing because the array is empty. You need to get the getTaskList() or write a similar method to get the data from neverTask table. You might have to do something like: "final String[] neverTasks = list.toArray(dbHelper.getTaskList());" if the existing code is to work without modifications...